# PHP searching multidimensional array for item

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I currently have an array set up like this:

```
$u_id= array(
    array(
        NUM=>'2770', DESC=>'description one'
    ), 

    array(
        NUM=>'33356', DESC=>'description two'
    ), 

    array(
        NUM=>'13576', DESC=>'description three'
    ),

    array(
        NUM=>'14141', DESC=>'description four'
    )
);
```

I need to be able to pass a number through this array as `$num` (corresponding to a NUM=>'' in the array), and store the corresponding DESC=>'' as a string. For example, searching for "2770" would return "description one".

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: I have found multidimensional arrays to be a hassle in the past and they tend to get a bit confusing. I would do what JacobM suggests if this is all you are storing in each array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($arrays as $arr){
  if($arr['NUM']==$num){
    return $arr['DESC'];
  }
}
```

Comment: no problem, but Jacob is right, if you have the option of restructuring your array you should:)

Answer (score 4):

Are you constrained to this array structure?  Because a more efficient structure would be to just do

```
$u_id= array(
     '2770' => 'description one',
     '33356' => 'description two',
     '13576' => 'description three',
     '14141' => 'description four'
);
```

That is to say, you just assume that the key is the number and the value is the description, rather than naming them explicitly.  Then the code to find the correct description is just `$u_id[2770]` (or whichever).

If that's not acceptable, you could also do

```
$u_id= array(
    '2770' => array(
        NUM=>'2770', DESC=>'description one'
    ), 

    '33356' => array(
        NUM=>'33356', DESC=>'description two'
    ), 

    '13576' => array(
        NUM=>'13576', DESC=>'description three'
    ),

    '14141' => array(
        NUM=>'14141', DESC=>'description four'
    )
);
```

That is, the number is also used as the key to find the correct pair.  The code to find the correct description becomes `$u_id[2770]["NUM"]`.

In either of these scenarios, finding a given description from the number is a single step.  If you can't change the array structure, though, then you'd have to loop through the array to check (which could take as many steps as there are items in the array).

Comment: You make a good point. If you don't need any more elements just use an associative array where the NUM is associated with a DESC.

Comment: I can change the structure to the first example you gave, but how would I go about finding the description for any given number?

Comment: @John if you changed it to @JacobM 's first example, you a given description for $number would be `echo $u_id[$number]['DESC'];`

Comment: Edited to add a usage example, but the idea is that the number you're searching for is your array key, so if you have `$search_num='2770'` you can just get `$u_id[$search_num]` and that's your description.

Comment: Actually, @Christopher, if he's using my first example he wouldn't need `['DESC']`.  It would just be `$u_id[$number]`.

Comment: @JacobM Sorry - I said first example but looked at the second.

Comment: Alright, using `echo $u_id[2770];` returns the correct description, but how would I go about doing it with the original array I have? To find the description of the row, I would just use `$u_id[$row_number][DESC];`, but it doesn't work if I just pass in the number as `$u_id['2770'][DESC];`.

Comment: Using the original array, there's no way to simply get the correct item using a key, because you don't have a key.  You'd have to loop through every item and check for matching values.